# DB2 - Read Priviliges cannot read

Tags: sql, db2, privileges

I'm trying to read from a certain table (READTABLE) using an account (ACCOUNTX). This account has read (select) privileges on table, READTABLE. I checked this using:

```
from syscat.tabauth
where grantee = CURRENT USER and (SELECTAUTH = \'Y\' OR SELECTAUTH = \'G\')
```

This returned among others, READTABLE.

However, executing a statement in which I have `FROM READTABLE` I get the following error:

`[DB2/AIX64] SQL0204N  "ACCOUNTX.READTABLE is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704`

Why does this table get ACCOUNTX pre-pended to it? Or is my privilege-check query wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each table in DB2 belongs to a schema. Therefore, a fully qualified table name consists of both the schema name and the table name, separated by a dot.

If, when referencing a table, you do not qualify it with a schema name explicitly, DB2 will take the value of the `CURRENT SCHEMA` variable set in your session. By default `CURRENT SCHEMA` is initialized with the value of your authorization ID (username).

Apparently, your table `READTABLE` belongs to a schema different from `ACCOUNTX`. If you don't have permissions to read the table, the error will be different.