# Accessing table without using schema name

Tags: db2

I am new with DB2.

I am not able to get data from a table without using the schema name. If I use a schema name with table name, I am able to fetch data.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

It is giving me error, while

```
SELECT  FROM SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME;
```

is fetching a result.

What do I have to set up not to always have to use the schema name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DB2 - Read Priviliges cannot read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31727655/db2-read-priviliges-cannot-read)

Answer (score 2):

By default, your username is used as the schema name for unqualified object names. You can see the current schema with, e.g. `VALUES CURRENT SCHEMA`. You can change the current schema for you current session with `SET SCHEMA new_schema_name`, or via e.g. a JDBC connection parameter. Most query tools also have a place to specify/change the current schema.

See the manual page for SET SCHEMA https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001016.html

The full rules for the qualification of unqualified objects is here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000720.html#r0000720__unq-alias

E.g.

> Unqualified alias, index, package, sequence, table, trigger, and view names are implicitly qualified by the default schema.

However, you can create a **public alias** for a table, module or sequence if you wish to be able to reference it regardless of your `CURRENT SCHEMA` value.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000910.html

(P.S. all the above assumes you are using Db2 LUW)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`SET SCHEMA`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/fi/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001016.html) to set the default schema to be used in the session:

```
SET SCHEMA SCHEMA_NAME;
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

- When using **DBeaver** - **right click** on **connection** > **Connection Settings** > **Initialization**, and select your **default DB** and **default Schema**:

[image: DB2 configure defaults]

- After that, open your SQL Script and select **Active DB**:

[image]